# How to merge changes between local and remote branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in my git repository:

```
  capsule-os
* remotes/m/ics
```

capsule-os is branch with my local changes to the remotes/m/ics branch. I work with (and build) the capsule-os branch, but remotes/m/ics updates sometimes, and I want to sync this changes with my local branch (in fact, add my changes to this remote branch). What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Amber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374299/223092) is correct, but I thought it might be worth adding an answer with the alternative approach of rebasing rather than merging.*

If you haven't published your `capsule-os` branch yet, you may want to "rebase" your changes on to the updated `m/ics` branch, e.g. with:

```
# Make sure you're on the right branch:
git checkout capsule-os

# "Replay" all of your commits on top of m/ics, and update
# capsule-os to point to the result:
git rebase m/ics
```

(You might have to resolve some conflicts then - if you can't easily do that, you can put your `capsule-os` branch back to how it was originally with `git rebase --abort`.)

As an alternative, you can fetch the new version of the `ics` branch and rebase onto that in one go with:

```
git pull --rebase m ics
```

There are lots of different ways of using `git rebase`, but they all essentially involve taking a set of commits and, for each of those, trying to reapply the changes the commit introduced onto some other commit.  This is frequently used to "move" a set of commits onto an updated upstream branch, to keep the history simple.

The reason that I qualified this with "if you haven't published the `capsule-os` branch" is that rewriting the history of a branch can create difficulties for collaborators who are working on the original version of that branch.  However, if it's still private work, rebasing is a nice way to keep your branch up to date with upstream, and still keeping the history simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your remote is named `m`:

```
git pull m ics
```

http://gitref.org/remotes/#pull